# Force close in WebView- not working when it's in offline

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget, android-webview

I want to display website in online. When it's in offline mode, it should display the cached website.I created,but when it's in online it's working.But when it's in offline, it leads to force close.I dont know where I am making mistake.Please help me.

Coding are as follows:

```
    w=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    enableHTML5AppCache();
}

private void enableHTML5AppCache() {    
      w.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);
      w.getSettings().setAppCachePath("/data/data/"+ getPackageName() +"/cache");
      w.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
      w.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
      w.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
      cm = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(Activity.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

      if(cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())
         {
                w.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
            w.setInitialScale(1);
                w.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
         }
      else
         {
              w.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
              w.loadUrl("http://www.google.com/");
         }
}
```

And in manifest file, I have used permissions also

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: what does your logcat say ?

Comment: The logcat shows, "no such table:Deleted CacheResources"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cm.getActiveNetworkInfo()` can be equal to null when no network available

you need to check for network like this

```
if(cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())
```

see this [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getActiveNetworkInfo%28%29)